# Shouldn't this log each new udev added?

Tags: linux, udev

I added `/etc/udev/rules.d/00-test.rules` containing:

```
ACTION=="add",RUN="/usr/bin/echo Bonjour > /dev/kmsg"
```

which should basically log into `dmesg` every udev addition, but nothing happens.

**For learning purposes, how to execute an action on each udev addition?**

Comment: did you restarted udev?

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, with  `udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: my `echo` is at `/bin/echo`

Comment: On mine it works on both, I tried `/bin/echo` and it is the same: nothing happens.

Comment: @hek2mgl when you add this rule mentioned here, does something happen in your `dmesg` when you insert a USB stick?

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76934/discussion-between-basj-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: Can you try using `RUN+=...` ? Note the `+` sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it should be `RUN+=` instead of `RUN`.

Further you need to know that `udev` does not execute the program specified in `RUN` in a shell context. Meaning IO redirection like `> /dev/kmsg` is not available.

You need to write the rule like this:

```
ACTION=="add",RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo Bonjour > /dev/kmsg'"
```